# Ansible stuck when running remote expect script

Tags: expect, ansible

I am creating an ansible script to install `ispconfig` with no interaction. I am using expect to deal with `ispconfig` interactive install `php` script. I am installing it on `Ubuntu 14.04` using the `apt-get` version of expect and the latest version of ansible.

What happens it that after running the expect script ansible does not return.

The script I use is the following: [expect script on github](https://github.com/wiebew/ispconfig_install/blob/master/roles/ispconfig/templates/ispconfig.exp)

The output I get from the expect logfile is:

```
Stopping amavisd: amavisd-new.
Starting amavisd: amavisd-new.
 * Stopping ClamAV daemon clamd
   ...done.
 * Starting ClamAV daemon clamd
   ...done.
dovecot stop/waiting
dovecot start/running, process 30668
reload: Unknown instance:
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx
   ...done.
Installation completed.
string detected
```

When I run the script on the remote hosts it runs flawless. Doing it through ansible the script get executed but it does not return. Running ansible with -v does not show any log info while ansible is waiting..

The relvant part of ansible script is:

```
  # as isconfig install is a interactive script we use expect to deal with that
  # by checking if ispconfig is present we make this an idempotent process  
  # if ispconfig absent the install will run
  - name: Check for installed ispconfig
    command: /usr/bin/test ! -e "/usr/local/ispconfig"
    register: ispconfig_absent
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: Copy expect script to configure ispconfig
    template: src=ispconfig.exp dest=/root/ispconfig.exp
    when: ispconfig_absent|success

  - name: set perm for script to configure ispconfig
    file: path=/root/ispconfig.exp mode=0750
    when: ispconfig_absent|success

  - name: configure ispconfig
    command: "/root/ispconfig.exp"
    when: ispconfig_absent|success

  - name: remove ispconfig configure script
    file: path=/root/ispconfig.exp state=absent
    when: ispconfig_absent|success
```

Doing ps aux shows that the expect script is defunct. The ansible process waits for the process to return.

Any clues what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so it seems that ansible doesn't like expect script amongst others. So here is the solution that worked for me (with example):

```
- name: run the expect script which will interactively install crashplan
  command: expect install_crashplan.expect {{ crashplan_backup_drive }} chdir=/opt/CrashPlan_test/CrashPlan-install
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'CrashPlan has been installed' not in command_result.stdout"
```

If you add a debug rule(you might have to change the failed_when rule to force it complete) and print the dictionary variable command_result, you will see that it *does not contain any errors* and did in fact complete. But still it never returns!?

- So the way to fix it is that you provide it with a winning condition, so register the output for the expect script and then try to find a string that you are guaranteed to only show if the task completes. If you can find that string then the task completed otherwise it failed.
- You also want to bear in mind to use the **expect** program rather than just running the script with the **script** module. This kind of guarantees a return code in case the expect script doesn't.

Hope this helps someone!

Cheers.

Comment: Nice workaround!, I went by replacing expect with empty this worked also. http://empty.sourceforge.net/